# where i could find latest binary distribution of jss7

Tags: restcomm

I try to *install* `mobicents-Restcomm-JBoss-AS7`
but - found many src distributions, i don't want to go down the road - compiling the whole src tree.
Many docs point some urls - that i should look `mobicents-Restcomm-JBoss-AS7-*-zip`.
On github `jss7-8.0.0-179` is a source distrib.

any working link with binary?

going with source build - is a little pain to do a proof of concept...

if it matters:

```
CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)
java version "1.7.0_221"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (rhel-2.6.18.0.el7_6-x86_64 u221-b02)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.221-b02, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems all the binary have been removed from repo. You might to get binaries if you have it installed before now.